# Nginx run Proxy Pass on / and php Blog on /blog

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, nginx, webserver

I have a react application running on / on nginx. I want to enable a wordpress blog on /blog

This is my current config:

```
http {
upstream reactapp
{
server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
}

server {
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;

listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
     root /var/www/html;
     index index.php index.html index.htm;


     server_name www.xxxxxxx.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://reactapp;
   }


location /blog {
    index                               index.php index.html;
    try_files                           $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files                       $uri =404;
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout            3600s;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
        fastcgi_buffers                 4 128k;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
}
```

I want to run wordpress on the /blog sub directory and it's located /var/www/html/blog but it only loads the root pages, all sub pages do not work, either gives 404 or goes to /.

[image]

Comment: You should use: `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;`

Comment: Does not work. The admin files load, but the frontend files do not.. 
It tries to get content from the /

https://<domain>.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/icon.png the config in wordpress has https://<domain>.com/blog

Comment: What is `/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/icon.png`?

Comment: Just a file that's loading, it's loading from / and it should load from /blog with the above config

Comment: You have changed the [WordPress HOME and SITE URLs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) so any WordPress resources will be loaded from `/blog`. Could this be a link that's embedded into a WordPress post? Maybe you need to edit the post or set up a special `location` to handle legacy links.

Comment: I though that was the issue. But I started from scratch. doing wordpress install also does not load any css files. Attached image to original post

Comment: Figured out the issue was cloudflare cache, after disabling it, your solution worked